# Javascript Upload and real image refresh/reload

Tags: ajax, image, caching, upload, reload

I need to create, for a specific project, an image manager that works via Ajax (to get the list of images, display them, ...).

The upload of new images, or image modification, is done via an Ajax script (using the new javascript File API).
The upload works fine, but I encounter a problem in case of image modification : the image displayed by the browser after upload is the cached one and not the uploaded one !!

I know it's a classic cache problem, that can be solved via the 'imagesrc?new Date.getTime()' hack, but I can't use it here.
in fact, this hack doesn't really reload the image, it only create a new instance of the image into the cache, associated to the image url 'imagesrc?new Date.getTime()'.

So, if at any moment, into the image manager, I retry to display the image, without adding the '?new Date.getTime()' to the src, it will display again the old image.
And I either cannot add this hack systematically (because, for example, if the image manager needs to display a lot of very heavy images, it's usefull to get them from the browser cache until they are modified).

I searched a way to solve this problem on internet (really replace the cached image after a javascript upload instead of using the above hack), but I found nothing.

Is there a way to do this, or is it totally impossible ?
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your server to send [ETag-headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) for the images.

An ETag is a hash-value of the file that changes when the file is modified. If an ETag is sent, the browser will add an `If-None-Match`-header containing the last received ETag of that ressource on its next request and the server will respond with `304: not modified` to save traffic if nothing has changed or send the new file if there is one.